# Hanks PasscodeView

Tags: android, kotlin

I used hanks passcodeview view in my application.
Following this https://github.com/hanks-zyh/PasscodeView

But I am getting 'Error inflating class com.hanks.passcodeview.PasscodeView'

Also, passcodeview layout xml file(design) looks like this,

[image: passcodeview layout xml file looks like this]

Comment: Have you used implement instead of compile?

Comment: I used implement

Answer (score 0):

add this to your build.gradle (app module)

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

and sync your project everything will be perfect

Answer (score 0):

This is very Simple Problem .I had this problem and I solved it. Follow this step

```
implementation "com.hanks:passcodeview:0.1.2"

implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

repositories{

jcenter() \\add

}

implement .
```